# How to find a matrix $C$ such that $C^{-1}AC$ is in Jordan block form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

$A:=\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -1\\ 
4 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

Now, just to show I've done some working, at least to find $A$'s eigenvalues and deduced that it's not diagonalisable:
[image]

Any hints/advice?
Thanks

Comment: They've got algebraic and geometric multiplicity mixed up, the geometric multiplicity never exceeds the algebraic one.

Comment: 'they'? Ok; I'll correct it. Thanks.

Comment: I said "they", because I couldn't understand why you would post an image of something you typed yourself. You know, you can actually type text in the box for asking a question ;-) You can even get formulas to show up beautifully, just put some dollars around them (the ones on your keyboard).

Comment: Yes, but I'd already typed it up on Word, so I thought it'd be much faster and easier just to print screen my working than to re-type everything up in Latex. Sorry it's not up to your typographical standard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a $2 \times 2$ (say complex) matrix $A$ which is not diagonalizable, there is a method to determine the conjugating matrix $C$ such that $C^{-1}AC$ is in Jordan form. The only way that $A$ can fail to be diagonalizable is if the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has a repeated root $s,$ but $A \neq sI.$ Then the only possibility for the Jordan form is $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} s & 1\\0&s \end{array} \right)$. In order to have trace $2s$ and determinant $s^{2},$ the matrix $A$ must either  have the form $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} s+a &  ta\\\frac{-a}{t} & s-a \end{array} \right)$ for some $a,t \neq 0,$ or have one of the forms $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} s & t\\0&s \end{array} \right)$ or $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} s & 0\\t&s \end{array} \right)$ for some non-zero $t.$ We have to solve the equation $AC = C \left( \begin{array}{clcr} s & 1\\0&s \end{array} \right)$ with ${\rm det} C \neq 0.$ This reduces to solving one of the equations $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} a &  ta\\\frac{-a}{t} & -a \end{array} \right)C = C\left( \begin{array}{clcr} 0 & 1\\0&0 \end{array} \right)$ or $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} 0 &  t\\0 & 0 \end{array} \right)C = C\left( \begin{array}{clcr} 0 & 1\\0&0 \end{array} \right)$ or $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} 0 &  0\\t & 0 \end{array} \right)C = C\left( \begin{array}{clcr} 0 & 1\\0&0 \end{array} \right).$ This can always be done.
In your case, you have $s = 4, a = 2$ and $t = \frac{-1}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

In *general* there is no *easy* way to find a Jordan basis. But for small matrices you must just ensure that the first vector of each Jordan block is a true eigenvector, and every next vector in the same Jordan block maps by $A-\lambda I$ to the previous vector. Since the block here is certain to be $2\times 2$, just choose the eigenvector $r_1$ you found as first basis vector, and as other basis vector any solution $r_2$ to $(A-\lambda I)r_2=r_1$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'any' solution? There is only one satisfying the equation at the bottom.

Comment: And why does your equation work (in general)?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions to the equation I wrote, because $A-\lambda I$ has a non-trivial kernel, which you computed: it is the eigenspace. And I did not say this method works _in general_, but it works when the algebraic multiplicity is no more than$~2$. Because then however you choose $r_1$, the equation has solutions for $r_2$. [What can go wrong in general is that you might need to choose your first vector more carefully than just any eigenvector. This happens first when the algebraic multiplicity is$~3$ while the geometric multiplicity is$~2$.]